# Discrete Weighted Hardy Inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

### Classical Hardy Inequality

Discrete [Hardy's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%27s_inequality) states that

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ be a sequence of non-negative real numbers and $p>1$ then,
> $$
> \left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n a_j \right)^p \right)^{1/p} \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n^p \right)^{1/p}.
> $$

An integral version states that,

> Let $f$ be a positive function and $p>1$ then,
> $$
>  \left(\int_0^\infty  \left(\frac{1}{x} \int_{0}^x f(t) \, dt \right)^p \, dx \right)^{1/p} \leq \frac{p}{p-1} \left(\int_0^\infty f(x)^p \, dx \right)^{1/p}.
> $$

Notice that everything breaks down when $p=1$. Is there anything for $p=1$? The answer is YES. But we have to add an extra weight.

### Weighted Hardy Inequality

In particular, for the integral case we have that,

> Let $f$ be a positive function and $p \geq 1$ and $r>0$ then,
> $$
> \left(\int_0^\infty  \left(\int_{0}^x f(t) \, dt \right)^p x^{-r-1} \, dx \right)^{1/p} \leq \frac{p}{r} \left(\int_0^\infty (x f(x))^p x^{-r-1}\, dx \right)^{1/p}.
> $$

This result appears in the book *Singular Integrals and Differentiability Properties of Functions* written by **Elias M. Stein** in Appendix A.

And going back to the discrete case I would like to get the same result, i.e. if
$\{a_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a sequence of non-negative real numbers , with $p\geq 1$ and $r>0$ then

$$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j \right)^p n^{-r-1} \right)^{1/p} \leq \frac{p}{r} \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty (n a_n)^p n^{-r-1}\right)^{1/p}.
$$

So far, I have been able to prove the same inequality but with a constant worse than $\frac{p}{r}$. In particular, I have proven it considering the step function $\tilde{a}(x)$ defined as

$$
\tilde{a}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
0, \quad x \in(0,1] \\
a_n, \quad x \in(n, n+1] \text { for } n \in \mathbb{N} ,
\end{array}\right.
$$

and applying the integral version of the inequality.

#### Question

Is there any reference where they present this kind of result? Or do you have any idea if it is possible to obtain the bound that I'm looking for.